# show all files in working directory as tree except ignored files

Tags: git

Currently I am using `fd | as-tree` to check the effect of my `.gitignore` file.

Suppose my directory tree is like:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c
│   │   │   ├── dir
│   │   │   │   └── test
│   │   │   └── sample.adoc
│   │   ├── dir
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   └── sample.adoc
│   ├── dir
│   │   └── test
│   └── sample.adoc
├── dir
│   └── test
└── src
    ├── dir
    │   └── test
    └── sample.adoc
```

If I use, `dir/` in my `.gitignore`, `fd | as-tree` shows:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c
│   │   │   └── sample.adoc
│   │   └── sample.adoc
│   └── sample.adoc
└── src
    └── sample.adoc
```

Is there any git command which list all not-ignored files in a tree format?

Comment: `git ls-files -cmo --exclude-standard`. Check out the man page and play with the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git ls-files --exclude-standard -co` will list all files that are not ignored.

Look at its options (`git help ls-files`) for variations on the files listed (in the index, in the worktree+index ...)

I think you will still need an external command to display it as a tree.

Comment: I do not need to see tracked files. I need to see all files that are not ignored by the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: That would be `ls-files -co` then

Comment: I just checked, giving `*` in my `.gitignore` file. `ls-files -co` shows all the files.

Comment: Files are still tracked, you would need to also run `git rm --cached -rf *`

Comment: tested it on an actual repo : I had forgotten about the `--exclude-standard` option. updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not specifically answer the question as it does not use `git` but the `tree` command has added a `--gitignore` flag as of tree [Version 2.0.0 (12/21/2021)](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/CHANGES). This should do what you need.

If you have a version of tree older than this and you have [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) installed you could create an alias like this to achieve something similar.

```
alias itree='rg --files | tree --fromfile'
```